# NodeJs - Excel file - Best way to unmerge cells in an Excel sheet - Opensource

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, excel, tauri

So I'm creating a **`Tauri-React`** desktop application for my business.

I need to know the best **JavaScript** library or code to help me unmerge cells in an excel file. I have been using `xlsx-populate` it works great until you realize the cells it unmerges their values are gone, no problem just store the values before unmerging and assign to the lowest value cell but I can't even get the values from the merged cells, it is just an array of attributes no value. To be more specific there is absolutely no value whatsoever in the merge cells that take up a 2x2 or greater pattern `(2 rows and 2 or more columns vice versa)`. It will return value for merged cells 1x2 and greater `(1x2 - 1 row with 2 or more column vice versa)`.

I am trying to automate my work flow. My only solution is opening the spreadsheet with MS Excel and unmerge the cells manually but we are devs where's the fun in that. I have rewritten the code in **Python** using `openpyxl` it works excatly as intended however, it is **SUPER SLOOOOW!!!** when processing an excel file with over 40,000 rows x 22 colmuns (the excel files are data dumps and no the service provider does not export in csv or json :( just excel or pdf).

```
const XlsxPopulate = require("xlsx-populate");
    
const unMergeExcel = async ({ fileName }) => {
  const fileLocation = path.resolve(__dirname, "excel", `${fileName}`);
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const workbook = await XlsxPopulate.fromFileAsync(fileLocation);
      const ranges = await workbook.sheet(0)._mergeCells;

      for (var range in ranges) {
        console.log(await workbook.sheet(0).cell(range).value()[0][0]);
        await workbook.sheet(0).range(range).merged(false);
      }

      await workbook.toFileAsync(
        path.resolve(__dirname, "excel_um", `${fileName}`)
      );
      resolve(true);
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });
};
```

The results of this console log:

```
console.log(await workbook.sheet(0).range(range).value()[0][0]);
```

Result:

> **row x columns**

```
[
  { name: 'r', attributes: {}, children: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { name: 'r', attributes: {}, children: [ [Object], [Object] ] }
] //2x2
[
  { name: 'r', attributes: {}, children: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { name: 'r', attributes: {}, children: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { name: 'r', attributes: {}, children: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { name: 'r', attributes: {}, children: [ [Object], [Object] ] }
] //2x4
[
  { name: 'r', attributes: {}, children: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { name: 'r', attributes: {}, children: [ [Object], [Object] ] }
] //2x2
[
  { name: 'r', attributes: {}, children: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { name: 'r', attributes: {}, children: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { name: 'r', attributes: {}, children: [ [Object], [Object] ] }
] //2x3
[
  { name: 'r', attributes: {}, children: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { name: 'r', attributes: {}, children: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { name: 'r', attributes: {}, children: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { name: 'r', attributes: {}, children: [ [Object], [Object] ] }
] //2x4
PAYMENTS //1x3
DEDUCTIONS //1x3
Description //1x4
Hrs/Dys/Tsk //1x2
Rate //1x2
Amount //1x2
Amount //1x2
```

Answer (score 0):

i gonna try to help since you help me with _mergeCells informations.

when i try, i still got the value from unmerged cells. but if the value is gone you could try to access before merge with syntax:

```
sheet.cell('A1').value()
```

You can switch A1 with the first address in mergedCells

i hope i can help you as well. good luck